Can $C(X)$ be free as a $C_b(X)$-module?
Does there exist an example of a non-pseudocompact Tychonoff space $X$ such that $C(X)$ is free as a $C_b(X)$-module?
Here $C(X)$ is the ring of continuous functions $X\to\mathbb{R}$ and $C_b(X)\subseteq C(X)$ is the subring of bounded continuous functions.
From my previous question An example of $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} \left( {C(X)}/{C_b(X)} \right) = 1$, I have learned that if $X$ is not pseudocompact, the minimal number of generators of $C(X)$ as a $C_b(X)$-module is at least $\aleph_1$. Hence a "minimal" counterexample would have the property that $C(X) \cong \bigoplus\limits_{\aleph_1} C_b(X)$ as $C_b(X)$-modules.
Note that $C(X)$ is indeed torsion-free as a $C_b(X)$-module. Assume that $rm = 0$ where $r \in C_b(X)$, $m \in C(X)$ and $m \neq 0$. Now take any $s > 0$ and define
$$
\tilde{m}: X \to \mathbb{R}, $$ $$\tilde{m}(x) = \begin{cases} s & s \leq m(x) \\ m(x) & -s \leq m(x) \leq s \\ -s & m(x) \leq -s \\ \end{cases}
$$
Then it is clear that $\tilde{m} \in C_b(X)$, $r \tilde{m} = 0$ and $\tilde{m} \neq 0$. Hence $r$ is not a regular element. This shows that $C(X)$ is torsion-free over $C_b(X)$.
A first example of a nontrivial case would be $\mathbb{N}$. The question then becomes purely algebraic:

Is $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ free as a module over $\mathbb{R}_b^{\mathbb{N}}$?

I have also found when is a ring a free module over a subring? , but I don't think any of the conditions listed there apply here. Generally, neither $C(X)$ nor $C_b(X)$ are local or a PID.

Note that for pseudocompact spaces, we have $C(X) = C_b(X)$, so this case is not interesting. Also, the restriction to Tychonoff spaces is not actually a restriction, since for any topological space $X$ we have a Tychonoff space $Y$ and a surjection $X \to Y$ inducing an isomorphism $C(X) \cong C(Y)$.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No, it won't be free unless $C(X) = C_b(X)$.
Theorem. If $C(X)$ is a free $C_b(X)$-module then $X$ is pseudocompact.
Proof: Suppose $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is a base for $C(X)$ as a $C_b(X)$-module, so that every $f\in C(X)$ can be written uniquely as finite sum $f = \sum g_if_i$ where $g_i\in C_b(X)$.
If $j\in I$ let $f_j^2 = \sum g_if_i$ for $g_i\in C_b(X)$ and $h = \frac{1}{\max(|f_j|, 1)}$, then $(hf_j)\cdot f_j = \sum hg_if_i$ where $hf_j, hg_i\in C_b(X)$ so $hf_j = hg_j$ hence $f_j = g_j\in C_b(X)$.
It follows that every $f_j$ is bounded, so every $f\in C(X)$ must be bounded.  $\square$
